# Notify when credit card expired

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-subscriptions, paypal-webhooks

I´d like to notify to buyers when theirs credit card is about to expire and subscriptions would be possible cancelled or suspended.
As per PayPal documentation this is possible to archive using Webhooks (REST API) or IPN (NVP/SOAP Apis).

My question is:

**Which is the best approach to get as much information as possible to notify to the buyer by email?**

Thanks in advance.
Roberto.

Answer (score 0):

Are you working with REST APIs to build your payment requests?  If so, you'll have to use Webhooks.

If you're working with PayPal Standard buttons or Classic APIs, then you'll have to use IPN.

So that's really where your question lies.  You don't really have a choice depending on which method you're using to integrate the payments.

Once you know which one you need to use then you can review the notifications themselves to see which ones will give you the data you're after.

Comment: Hi Drew!. Yes, I´m using REST API to create plans and agreements from an SPA application. But apart from that,  I´m going to build a background server process to notify users when credits card are close to expire and thought it could be with webhooks or IPN (classic API´s). I guess my background process does not depend on which approach (REST API or Classic API´s) uses SPA web application. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, if you're working with REST you need to use Webhooks.

Comment: @DrewAngell, In case of Paypal Subscription and Webhooks, which event I will get when a payment is failed due to any reason?

Comment: @harishsharma I'm actually not seeing a clear answer on that in the docs.  Would have to register all webhooks on an app, and then trigger a failed billing agreement payment to see gets posted.

Comment: Yeah, actually I also checked in the docs, but didn't found something useful,